# hostname resolution fails

Tags: hadoop, docker

I am running two docker containers one is for hadoop basic services and other is for flume. Services are running successfully. I linked two containers env variables are automatically set by docker successfully.

```
1.2.3.4    7ab4ffb30dc0
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback

fe00::0 ip6-localnet
```

This is My /etc/hosts file for hadoop. When i run

```
hadoop fs -ls /
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://127.0.0.1:8020/
```

Works fine. But if i run

```
hostname
```

it returns 7ab4ffb30dc0

So i tried

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://1.2.3.4:8020/
```

it says Call From 7ab4ffb30dc0/1.2.3.4 to 7ab4ffb30dc0:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see: http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the hadoop instance is running the hadoop service, from your [link](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused), it shows that the server is responding, but there is no service available. Check the logs to ensure it is running (assuming hadoop is instance name):

`docker logs hadoop`

If the service is in fact running, perhaps the exposed port is not the port you expected, it depends how you started the hadoop instance, if you ran something similar to:

`docker run -P --name=hadoop hadoop`
This will map the exposed ports to random ports and you must use the environment variable that gives you the port, if the instance is linked as the name hadoop:

HADOOP_PORT_8020_TCP_PORT # format *PORT*__PORT

there are several environment variables set, see [Docker User Guide](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/) Using these variables, you could run your command like this:

`hadoop fs -ls hdfs://${HADOOP_PORT_8020_TCP_ADDR}:${HADOOP_PORT_8020_TCP_PORT}`

Comment: Yes, Except 8020, 50070,50105,50060,50090,50030,80,22 are present in env. I exposed only these ports. Doesn't 8020 come from core-site.xml

Comment: I am unsure what core-site.xml is. But you have to expose the ports as well ensure that your service is running.